# How to change paint through KeyListener?

Tags: java, swing

Hello I wish to add another story to a house drawn in paintComponent through clicking the ARROW UP key and remove it through clicking the ARROW DOWN key. But I have problems regarding the KeyListener and I dont understand what has to be fixed about this code.

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

Main viewer class

```
public class HouseViewer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    frame.setSize(700, 700);
    frame.setTitle("Cool house program");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JComponent component = new HouseComponent();
    frame.add(component);
    frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Component class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;



public class HouseComponent extends JComponent implements KeyListener {

    private boolean more;
    private boolean less;
    private boolean def;



    public HouseComponent(){
      def = true;
       this.addKeyListener(this); 
    }


    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){




     if (def) {

        // Default

        // 1st rectangle
        g.drawRect(230, 180, 200, 200);
        // roof
        g.drawLine(230, 180, 330, 100);
        g.drawLine(430, 180, 330, 100);
        // door and window
        g.drawRect(260, 280, 50, 100);
        g.drawRect(350, 310, 45, 45);
    }

    if(more) {    

        // roof
        g.drawLine(230, 180, 330, 45);
        g.drawLine(430, 180, 330, 45);

        // 2nd story rectangle
        g.drawRect(230, 180, 200, 100);

        // 1st rectangle
        g.drawRect(230, 180 + 100, 200, 200);


        // door and window
        g.drawRect(260, 280 + 100, 50, 100);
        g.drawRect(350, 310 + 100, 45, 45);

    }


    if (less) {

        // 1st rectangle
        g.drawRect(230, 180, 200, 200);
        // roof
        g.drawLine(230, 180, 330, 100);
        g.drawLine(430, 180, 330, 100);
        // door and window
        g.drawRect(260, 280, 50, 100);
        g.drawRect(350, 310, 45, 45);

    }








    }



     public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();



        switch( key )
        { 

        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

        more = true;
        less = false;
        def = false;
        repaint();


        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

        more = false;
        less = true;
        repaint();



    }

    }


    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }


     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {


    }


}
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to make key events change the house painting

Comment: Add a `break;` at the end of each `case`. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Okay I have added it. It hasn't changed anything though.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code?

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add any debug code to see if your listener code is being executed?

KeyEvents are dispatched to the component with focus. By default a JComponent is not focusable so the component won't receive the event.

The better solution is to use `Key Bindings`. Key Bindings will work even when a component doesn't have focus.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for a comparison between using a KeyListner and Key Bindings. It will show what you need to do to get the KeyListener working by making the component focusable, although there is never any guarantee that the component won't lose focus.

Comment: I'm forced to use a KeyListener. What can I replace the JComponent with?

Comment: @Darknax, was just in the middle of adding additional info to the answer.

Comment: Woah I fixed it. All I had to do was add this.setFocusable(true) to the constructor. Thanks !

Comment: @Darknax, glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add `break;` for all switch cases. Also rename method `paintComponent` to `paint`

Comment: I'm not sure, but if you look at sources of `paint` method you can see that 'paintComponent` method under condition, so classes can not call `paintComponent` directly (because it's protected) and another classes call `paint` method. Maybe here was problem